# contour integral to show the sum of a series

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $Γ_n$ be the cycle that traverses the square with vertices
±(n+
$\frac 12$ 
)(1±i). Show that there is a constant δ > 0 such that |sin(πw)| > δ
for all w ∈
$U_n$ $Γ_n$.

By considering the integral $$\int_{Γ_n}\frac {\pi}{w^2sin(w\pi)}\, dw$$

show that $1 −
\frac 14+ \frac19−\frac1{16}+ · · · =\frac{π^2}{12}.$

The first part was straightforward. I just used the definition of the complex sine to show that |sin(πw)| only has zeroes at w = k, where k is any integer. That means that $Γ_n$ has 1+2n poles. The residues everywhere except at zero seem to cancel each other out, but I'm not sure how to show that rigorously. As in how can I use $$\int_{Γ_n}\frac {\pi}{δw^2}\, dw$$ for which the residue is obvious at the simple poles, to solve the residue for the original integral. I'm also not sure how to go about finding the residue at 0.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.

First, show that $\lim_{n\to \infty} I_n = 0$, where $I_n$ is your integral. Using your inequality about the $\sin$, this couldn't be hard.

Then apply the residue theorem to find an expression for $I_n$. As you saw,  the poles of the function $w \to \frac{\pi}{w^2 \sin (\pi w)}$ are at the integers in the domain.

In the end, you'll have something of the form $\sum_{a \in \Delta_n} \mathrm{Res}(f,a) \to 0$ where $\Delta_n$ is all the poles of the function inside the contour $\Gamma_n$. The conclusion will follow immediately.

**edit**. In the end, you'll have the following equality  :

$$2\pi \sum_{n \in\mathbb{Z}^*} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2} = \pi \mathrm{Res}(f, 0)$$

where $f(z) = \big(z^2 \sin (\pi z ) \big)^{-1}$. All you have to do is calculating the residue of this function at $0$. For this, you could write $z^2 \sin (\pi z) = z^3(1 - h(z))$ and expand.